# Vuejs: incorrect value on imported json file [Vue: 2.6.12]

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vuejs2 [version 2.6.12]. Trying to import a local JSON file.

JSON File content: {"name":"John", "age":30}

```
import json from '../static/data.json'
```

I am building the project by "npm run build" from CLI.

I am changing the JSON file content now:
New JSON File content: {"name":"Doe", "age":30}

Now I am Going to the "dist" folder and opening the index.html file. I am using the "name" on my template and seeing the "name" to be "John"

My Component data:

```
    export default{
      name: 'App',
      data () {
        return {
           name: json.name,
      },
      mounted () {
        //incorrect data. i have changed the name to "Doe", but still it is showing "John"
        console.log(this.name) //logging John
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the build, imported json file also will mix with javascript.

If you change the name in json file after building the project, you won't get new value.

Try this instead,
Change the name in json and create the build.

Comment: i will get the name dynamic in the json file. I cannot build every time

Comment: Are you using any API to get json data dynamically?

If yes, Just the set the value of "name" variable to the response data.